# Flutter GoogleMaps SearchMapPlaceWidget this code doesnot animate the camera to the selected location

Tags: flutter, api, google-maps

hello guys this search widget it does give you the autocomplete list of the location but the thing is when i press on the location it doesnot take me to it i am using the places API

```
 Stack(
              children: [
                GoogleMap(
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                  zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: widget.userPosition,
                    zoom: 16,
                  ),
                  onMapCreated: (controller) {
                    setState(() {
                      _googleMapController = controller;
                    });
                  },
                  markers: {
                    if (_destination != null) _destination,
                  },
                  onLongPress: _addMarker,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 60, left: 10),
                  child: SearchMapPlaceWidget(
                    hasClearButton: true,
                    placeType: PlaceType.cities,
                    placeholder: 'Enter The Location',
                    apiKey: '///////',
                    onSelected: (Place place) async {
                      Geolocation geolocation = await place.geolocation;
                      _googleMapController.animateCamera(
                        CameraUpdate.newLatLng(geolocation.coordinates),
                      );
                      _googleMapController.animateCamera(
                        CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(geolocation.bounds, 0),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: How did you initialized `_googleMapController`? Are you getting any errors? I tried your code and it is working properly.

Comment: thanks man the problem was that i did not add the geolocator and the geolocation APIs